# Spring Boot example RESTful service will not work after create new packages

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

i'm working right now on the small tutorial for restful webservice with Spring Boot http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/.

I did all the things on the tutorial and i was successful with the trial.
After than, i renamed some classes and moved them to new packages.
i did a mvn clean install aund tried the example again, but i got a 404 error.

It seems cause to my little refactoring, but what can i do to rebuild the project with maven?

thanks a lot

Comment: Could you be more specific about your *little refactoring*?

Comment: Show your project structure

Comment: My little refactoring was just rename the controller class and the resource class and move them to new packages in my project.

Comment: What about a *little* more specific? The project is tiny, you could easily show us the whole code and structure.

Comment: What for information do you need?

Comment: @piet what classes did you rename? what packages did you move them to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that new packages you are created are under the package where Application.java is located.

Or else you have to add `@ComponentScan(takes package name)` annotation to Application.java file to detect those classes.

Comment: thanks for your answer, that was very helpful. Now it works.